# Broken components after building Gatsby

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, netlify

The site loses all functionalities after building it. In develop mode everything works fine, but when I build the website it looks like all scripts are missing. Bootstrap (Carousel DropDowns) are not responding, leflet map and background image not loading and react-multi-carousel do not work. I don't see any errors in the browser console, of course I ran `gatsby clean` before building. I uploaded the project to netlify. Below I am enclosing the json package:

```
{
  "name": "Website",
  "private": true,
  "description": "Description",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "license": "0BSD",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "gatsby build",
    "develop": "gatsby develop",
    "format": "prettier --write \"**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,json,md}\"",
    "start": "npm run develop",
    "serve": "gatsby serve",
    "clean": "gatsby clean",
    "test": "echo \"Write tests! -> https://gatsby.dev/unit-testing\" && exit 1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.35",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.15.3",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.3",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.14",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
    "gatsby": "^3.2.1",
    "gatsby-background-image": "^1.5.0",
    "gatsby-image": "^3.2.0",
    "gatsby-link": "^3.2.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-image": "^1.2.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-postcss": "^4.2.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-react-helmet": "^4.2.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-react-leaflet": "^3.0.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-recaptcha": "^1.0.5",
    "gatsby-plugin-robots-txt": "^1.5.5",
    "gatsby-plugin-sass": "^4.2.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-sharp": "^3.2.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-sitemap": "^3.2.0",
    "gatsby-remark-images": "^4.2.0",
    "gatsby-source-filesystem": "^3.2.0",
    "gatsby-transformer-remark": "^3.2.0",
    "gatsby-transformer-sharp": "^3.2.0",
    "gbimage-bridge": "^0.1.2",
    "leaflet": "^1.7.1",
    "node-sass": "^5.0.0",
    "postcss": "^8.2.9",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-animations": "^1.0.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.5.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
    "react-leaflet": "^3.1.0",
    "react-multi-carousel": "^2.6.2",
    "react-scripts": "^4.0.3",
    "styled-components": "^5.2.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "http-proxy-middleware": "^1.1.0",
    "netlify-lambda": "^2.0.3",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
    "prettier": "^2.2.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the browser's console output?

Comment: As I mentioned in the post, there are no bugs in the console, after all the other plugins were kicked out, the bootstrap started working, so probably one of them is biting the others.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved the problem by wrapping the leaflet maps in Loadable

```
import React from 'react';
import Loadable from "@loadable/component"

const LoadableMap = Loadable(() => import("./map.js"))

export default LoadableMap;
```

Answer (score 0):

There's not much debug in the question however, to me, it seems that you are using some dependencies outside React's scope, which may potentially block [React's hydration](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/conceptual/react-hydration/) process, which may explain the problem described. For example, using Leaflet instead of [React's Leaflet](https://react-leaflet.js.org/) or (depending on its implementation) Bootstrap instead of [React's Boostrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/).

You should be able to change all React-unfriendly modules to React's ones without too much effort and that should fix your problems.

Keep in mind that if your project "work in `develop` and breaks in `build`" doesn't mean that your project work or stops working, it just means that is working under certain and specific circumstances. Basically, and summarizing (to avoid extending the answer), `gatsby develop` uses the browser as an interpreter, where there are, among other things, global objects like `window` or `document`. However, `gatsby build` occurs in the Node server, where at the build time, there are not global objects because there are not even created yet, that the main reason why you may face a different behavior between both scenarios but doesn't mean that the project stopped working magically.

You can read further details in the [Overview of Gatsby Build Process](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/conceptual/overview-of-the-gatsby-build-process/).

Another option, linked with blocking React's hydration, is that some component may be blocking that process because of its own behavior. Be careful when using global objects like `window` or `document` (or when importing modules that uses it), they use should be always be wrapped inside the following condition, as you can see from the [docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/debugging-html-builds/):

> When referencing window in a React component.
>
> ```
> import * as React from "react"
> // Check if window is defined (so if in the browser or in node.js).
> const isBrowser = typeof window !== "undefined"
> export default function MyComponent() {
>   let loggedIn = false
>   if (isBrowser) {
>     window.localstorage.getItem("isLoggedIn") === "true"
>   }
>   return <div>Am I logged in? {loggedIn}</div>
> }
> ```

Or when requiring a module:

> ```
> // Requiring a function causes an error during builds
> // as the code tries to reference window
> const module = require("module") // Error
>
> // Wrap the require in check for window
> if (typeof window !== `undefined`) {
>   const module = require("module")
> }
> ```

The same approach can be done using loadable components as the docs suggests but without providing any piece of code it's impossible to guess what should be its implementation.